# Can we destroy instance of an app in the background after opening it from a deep link?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Can we destroy instance of an app in the background after opening it from a deep link? Like you need to login first in that app in your phone before you can proceed in the browser. After successful login, is it possible to destroy the activity which is now in the background (in this case the screen is now the browser)?

I was able to finish the activity and in that case it navigates me back to the browser. But when I try to open the RECENT APPS BUTTON it still shows me the application on background.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml`, add `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` to MainActivity of your app like below:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It should work. For details please check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exclude).

**Note:** If  above doesn't work then please try by adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` as well.

Comment: Will try this out and will update later. Thank you @VicJordan

Comment: @Charessa sure. Please let me know once you try this.

Comment: I tried it and I can no longer see my app after clicking recent tabs button, is this possible on setting flags upon creating new Intent(AnotherActivity)?

Comment: @Charessa also please tell me which one helped? `excludeFromRecents="true"` or `launchMode="singleInstance"`?

Comment: excludeFromRecents="true" helped. My second question was that if I create a new Intent(Activity) and I wanted to still exclude it from recent apps but I don't want it to be set on manifest file (for it will affect all scenarios upon accessing that Activity)

Comment: @Charessa Adding `excludeFromRecents="true"` in manifest and adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` flag to Intent when you start the activity will have same effect for all scenarios BUT if you override finish() method and add `super.finishAndRemoveTask();` inside that then it will affect only when that activity is finished.